# Plotting time series directly with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series

[image]

In the above dataframe, all I want to create a line plot so that we have info on trends per year for each of the columns. I've read about pivot-table on related posts, but when I implement that, it says there are no numbers to aggregate. I don't want to aggregate something. I just need the y-axis in terms of the column numbers.

[image]

When I use plot() however, it plots year on the x-axis and only plots other column also on the x-axis. Why is this happening and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Answer**

```
# change the type of non numeric
piv['second_col'] = piv['second_col'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
piv['last_col'] = piv['last_col'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
# then plot
piv.plot(x='Year')
```

**Explanation**

The index of the `Dataframe` is the default `x-axis`, So you need to specify :

```
piv.plot(x='Year')
```

Or set the `Year` as index :

```
piv.set_index('Year').plot()
```

One more thing is that the `plot` function plot numeric values, the second and last columns type is `string` you can check :

```
df.dtypes
```

When you use `pandas.read_csv` to read a file it has to infer the data type. Sometimes it gets it wrong. You can forces pandas to try and convert the data to floating point numbers :

```
piv = piv.astype(float)
```

But you will get an error somthing like this :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2,499'
```

**But Why ?**

The data has a `comma-separated numeric value`, you need to remove it before converting to float

```
piv['name_of_column'] = piv['name_of_column'].str.replace(',','').astype(float)
```